# Broadcasting with two arrays of different lengths in a function (energy and time axis) to build a 2D array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, axes, array-broadcasting

I have a function that takes two axes as an input - a time axis and an energy axis - and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to generate the resulting 2D array through broadcasting, rather than in a for loop for one of the axes.

The function looks like this, and is also included in my code example: [diffusion equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jDqT.png)

Here's what I think is the naïve approach I've tried, with the two axes have different lengths and handling the time array in a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

def function(zeta, tau, alpha):
    return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha**2*tau)*np.exp(-zeta**2/(2*alpha**2*tau))

zeta = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
tau  = np.logspace(1e1, 1e9, 200)
alpha = 1e-6

res = np.zeros((len(tau), len(zeta)))
for i, t in enumerate(tau):
    res[i, :] = function(zeta, t, alpha)
```

But what I'd like to do is this:

```
res = function(zeta, tau, alpha)
```

Which gives the (I guess expected) error:

```
return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha**2*tau)*np.exp(-zeta**2/(2*alpha**2*tau))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (200,)
```

So is there a way to simultaneously broadcast the function across `zeta` and `tau`, and speed up the building of the 100x200 array `res`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a comment on [`np.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html): I believe you may want to use `tau  = np.logspace(1, 9, 200)` rather than `tau  = np.logspace(1e1, 1e9, 200)`. The docs say:

> In linear space, the sequence starts at base ** start (base to the power of start) and ends with base ** stop

The default value of `base` is 10.0, so `start` and `stop` of `1` and `9` would get a sequence from `10.0 ** 1` to `10.0 ** 9` which I believe may have been your intention.

Regarding the question about 2D broadcasting, I think this may be what you're looking for:

```py
X, Y = np.meshgrid(zeta, tau)
result = function(X, Y, alpha)
```

The idea comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857629/18135454) answer to a similar question.

> **UPDATE**:
> This should give the same result and save some space:
>
> ```py
> X, Y = np.meshgrid(zeta, tau, sparse=True)
> ```
>
> From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):
>
> > sparse coordinate grids are intended to be use with Broadcasting. When all coordinates are used in an expression, broadcasting still leads to a fully-dimensonal result array.

```py
import numpy as np
def function(zeta, tau, alpha):
    return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha**2*tau)*np.exp(-zeta**2/(2*alpha**2*tau))

zeta = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
tau  = np.logspace(1, 9, 200)
alpha = 1e-6

X, Y = np.meshgrid(zeta, tau)
result = function(X, Y, alpha)
[print(v, eval(v+'.shape')) for v in ['zeta', 'tau', 'result']]
print(f"\nresult:\n{result}")

res = np.zeros((len(tau), len(zeta)))
for i, t in enumerate(tau):
    res[i, :] = function(zeta, t, alpha)
print(f"\nres.shape {res.shape}")
print(f"\nres:\n{res}")

print(f"\nallclose()? {np.allclose(result, res)}")
```

Output:

```
zeta (100,)
tau (200,)
result (200, 100)

result:
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

res.shape (200, 100)

res:
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

allclose()? True
```

**Performance:**
Timeit for your original approach and the one above shows:

```
Timeit results:
foo_1 ran in 0.001397762499982491 seconds using 1000 iterations
foo_2 ran in 0.004021247100026813 seconds using 1000 iterations
```

So `meshgrid` looks to be about 3x faster for your inputs.

Full test code is here:

```py
import numpy as np
def function(zeta, tau, alpha):
    return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*alpha**2*tau)*np.exp(-zeta**2/(2*alpha**2*tau))

zeta = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
tau  = np.logspace(1, 9, 200)
alpha = 1e-6

from timeit import timeit

def foo_1(zeta, tau, alpha):
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(zeta, tau)
    result = function(X, Y, alpha)
    return result
def foo_2(zeta, tau, alpha):
    res = np.zeros((len(tau), len(zeta)))
    for i, t in enumerate(tau):
        res[i, :] = function(zeta, t, alpha)
    return res

n = 1000
print(f'Timeit results:')
for foo in ['foo_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(2)]:
    t = timeit(f"{foo}(zeta, tau, alpha)", setup=f"from __main__ import zeta, tau, alpha, {foo}", number=n) / n
    print(f'{foo} ran in {t} seconds using {n} iterations')
```

Comment: Yes that did it!! Thanks so much for the clear and quick fix!